# Devise installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a member authentication MVC myself, but found out that there is such gem called 'devise' So I am trying to remove my old authentication and use the devise. My older MVC was called member/members but this devise is using user/users MVC name.

But now when I am trying to use Devise. installing devise model and everything worked fine, but when I try to open up http://localhost:3000/user/sign_up, I get the following error.

```
ArgumentError in Devise/registrations#new

Showing /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/devise-1.1.3/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #6 raised:

syntax error on line 163, col 9: `  session:'
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4:   <%= devise_error_messages! %>
5: 
6:   <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
7:   <%= f.text_field :email %></p>
8: 
9:   <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
Rails.root: /home/administrator/Ruby/myilgi_v4_ruby

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump
```

I do not know where that **syntax error on line 163, col 9: `   session:'** is coming from.
I removed the session table, and session migration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

I had added some locale changes for session in config/locales/en.yml file.
After removing session and everything, I forgot to delete the translation from the locale file. After deleting it, everything worked out like a charm.

Comment: and it seems that rails does not catch error from locale file. Line 163, col9: session: meant to be a line163 of a locale file, but none of error messages showed that.